High lift devices on stunt planes
Assume a symmetric airfoil for a stunt plane.  But, assume you'd also like to generate a higher lift coefficient than a single symmetric foil can reasonably achieve.  I picture the arrangement looking somewhat like a normal wing with a separate trailing high-lift element deployed, but with both elements un-cambered and the second element being movable to either above or below the main wing.  I think it should work better than a symmetric foil with a normal trailing edge flap.
What lift coefficient and L/D could this achieve?

Can you edit your question to make it so that a single question is clearly posed? I see "Couldn't you use a separate symmetric airfoil... ?" and "What kind of performance is possible?" I suggest you add another paragraph with a single sentence that contains the exact question you want answered. That will make it easier for folks to help out.

Try a bi-plane.  Their wing structure is also very strong.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you mean something like an aileron?

The correct terminology is an aerobatic airplane.
High-lift devices on symmetrical airfoils are not fundamentally different from those on cambered airfoils, but if you want to use them in both directions, a simple camber flap is all that remains.
Take the Mü-28 aerobatic glider as an example. It uses a symmetric Wortmann airfoil with a full-span camber flap of 25% of chord. The activation is automatic: A bob weight will move the flap to a deflection which is proportional to the load factor, so in inverted flight it moves opposite to the movement in upright flight. Also, this helps to increase the maximum load factor in high-g maneuvers.

Mü 28 in inverted flight (source). The negative flap deflection should be easy to see.

the second element being movable to either above or below the main wing

This sounds like a Junkers flap. Moving something above or below the wing will require a mechanism and will increase drag markedly. After all, Junkers only used that flap on slow designs; their faster designs all went back to conventional flaps.
In short: The added complexity will not be worth the gain. A camber flap will achieve mostly the same result for less weight and fewer failure modes.

Junkers flap on the Ju-87 (source).

Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. In the image it looks like there is a gap between main element and flap. But, when I look up the Mü 28 the flaps look normal. I assumed you could get a higher lift coefficient with a gap, like when large planes extend landing flaps. Race cars do something similar with multi element rear wings and while they first prioritize Cl, they must worry about drag too. Maybe you could support a spaced flap with flat vertical plates that pivot about points inside the main element so the flap position and angle of attack move together.

@PeterEaymond No, the light strip that looks like a gap is only the rear part of the fixed wing which is (I guess) reflecting sunlight. It looks like the picture has been taken late in the evening with a low sun. Yes, the gap will give a higher lift coefficient but not a better lift-to-drag ratio! Race car designs follow different rules; they even accept separated flow to cut lift without moving surfaces, so total drag can be lowered when less lift is required.

@PeterKämpf, couldn't we use a combination of the two? A bob-weight together with a distance-mounted flap? I think that would take away a lot of the complexity.

@ROIMaison In principle yes, but for low actuation forces the flap must be hinged at its quarter chord. Then its nose will be above the trailing edge for cases where it better sits below it (to avoid sitting in the boundary layer of the suction side of the wing) and vice versa. I do not see an advantage in this.

I'll admit, (non-aviation-alert) what I proposed was similar to an accepted practice for solid wing sails on certain racing sailboats. A sail has to work in both directions. In lighter winds and tacking downwind they need a high CL because apparent wind speed is reduced and sail area is limited. I thought you could get high CL using low drag elements and attached flow using a detached flap. Conventional flap drag must climb pretty fast past some angle with a lower CL limit. The sharp profile transitions seem limiting.  Can someone recommend windows 11 software to play with this?

@PeterEaymond Yes, that is an interesting case. L/D is also important for sailboats - the better, the harder they can sail into the wind. Probably the gapped flap would also make sense for aerobatic planes after all, but to my knowledge nobody has tried it. Almost all planes fly exclusively right side up, and there is a mountain of literature how to design the gapped flap for one direction. BTW; gapped flaps make most sense during approach and landing when you want a lower L/D.
